# What causes hg rebase to leave a totally empty changeset?

Tags: mercurial, rebase

Let's say you rebase changeset `B` on top of changeset `W`. It can happen that `B` is totally redundant to changes already in `W` and its ancestors. When this occurs, *most of the time* Mercurial will issue a message like

> "note: rebase of `15589:09f53ec1b2dc` created no changes to commit"

and then `B` is simply removed. That's fine.

But once in a while instead it leaves `B` in existence as a child of `W`, **but `B` is totally empty**. Not one file listed. And if you subsequently rebase `B` again, it usually goes away as described above. (Or you can strip it).

This happens infrequently enough that I haven't been able to spot any pattern. Maybe ... 10-20% of the time?

But I'd like to understand what's going on because it adds some extra steps and definitely is confusing to more novice HG users.

Comment: Interesting. I have not seen this, but then again all of my actual work moved to Git quite a while ago as companies changed hands or went out of business or whatever. This *should* be impossible, not because hg can't do it internally (that's easy) but because it usually checks for an empty changeset and *doesn't* store it. I wonder if it's a bug that happens when the chain length gets long enough to warrant a fresh copy of some file...

Comment: @torek I wonder about a bug too... the cases I've seen this have only been rebasing usually 2-3 changsets only.

Comment: If it has to do with the chain lengths, it won't matter how many changesets you have now but rather how long a delta chain some manifest-listed file has internally. But that's all just speculation...

Comment: @torek thanks for your insight, I'm quite unfamiliar with the internals. Do you think this is worth reporting to HG as a potential bug?

Comment: Could be. I know HG is still actively maintained and developed. Ideally though you'd have a reproducer, and I suspect that's going to be hard to construct.

Comment: @torek I just saw another example of this. Do you know if there is any debug info (or other details) which I could save / extract that could be useful?

Comment: It's been too long since I've done anything inside Mercurial. There's a `--debugger` option that runs commands under the debugger; you'd want to set some breakpoints and continue. Which breakpoints...? The last time I did anything I had to update from Hg 2.x to 4.x and do a lot of single stepping.